# No reconoce la variable volverjugar

Tags: java

No reconoce la variable volverjugar

```
do{
   do{
      Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Introduce numero: ");
      numero = teclado.nextInt();
      System.out.println(numero);
      cont++;
      } while ( numero != rand );
        System.out.println("Intentos partida:" + cont);

  //¿Volver a jugar?
  Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar?(si/no): ");
  volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
  System.out.println(volverjugar);
 } while ( volverjugar != "si" );
```

Comment: Cual es el error que sale?, cuales son los datos de entrada que pasa?, intente colocando la variable `volverjugar` (Sugiero la variable `volverAJugar`) antes del primer `do` y en el `while` compare con `equals` `while(!volverjugar.equals("si");` De igual formal esa lógica no funcionaria porque al decir que `si` el programa finalizaria.

Comment: Dónde la tienes definida?